# Programmed-current mode and hystereis control for DC converters

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics

Could anyone please advise if the following understandings of DC converters are correct?

(1) The output of buck/boost/buck-boost converter should be regarded as voltage source, i.e. it can give a constant voltage regardless of the loading.

(2) A converter operating under programmed-current mode is a current source. That means it can give a constant current regardless of the loading.

(3) A converter operating under current hysteresis control is a current source - giving a constant current regardless of the loading.

If the above three notions are true:

(4) Consider a buck/boost/buck-boost converter operating under programmed-current mode. Should it be a current source or a voltage source?

(5) Similarly, consider a buck/boost/buck-boost converter operating under hysteresis current mode. Should it be a current source or a voltage source?

Thank you.

Comment: 2 and 3 answer 4 and 5. What's the problem here?

Comment: @BrianDrummond Thanks. I have questions because I found contradictions between (1) and (2) and between (1) and (3). The said DC converter should give a constant voltage. Operating under programmed-current mode/hysteresis-control should give a constant current. Then how about a DC converter operating under the programmed-current mode/hysteresis-control? Should this converter give a constant voltage or a constant current?